# what type of user cookies should I store in my web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, cookies

hello everyone I'm building a website that will use a login system so what type of user cookies should I store in my web application  I have a  table and I have four columns for user ID and username, email password. and I just want to know  what type of user cookies should i store in my web application like should I store the email and password or I just should store something has a connection to user info like his ID in the database and is there particular ways of doing that such as a module to do that ?

```js
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: [/* secret keys */],

  // Cookie Options
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 24 hours
}))
```

Comment: You probably want to use `cookie-session` for express (http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html). Don't use ID, since if I switched my ID to yours, I could login as you. Storing password in cookies is also insecure.

Comment: thank you for helping me. But I just want to add something for each user has unique id should I use it because I may use the user Id in another section

Comment: Is this all on the frontend or are users intended to login to the site and such? If so, all that stuff like generating IDs should be handled on the backend with a database, not in cookies.

Comment: I'm working on application that the users can post things and I want to use their IDs to connect them with what they posted that's why I want to store user ID because it's unique and has a relation with user's posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it depens on what Web App you're trying to build. If it' more like a Shop I prefer to store an ID to keep track on the shopping cart, but if you're build something which is more like a portfolio you don't have to store any cookies.